# Unauthorized Bank transaction

Tags: forgery

Someone went to my bank they didn't have no check or my debit card they used it with withdrawal slip at the drive-thru and stole money like on four different trips and the bank isn't reimbursing my money what is my area of recourse

Comment: Welcome to Law SE. Unfortunately, we cannot give legal advice on specific cases. Laws differ from country to country, and each case is different. You need a lawyer. In many places, lawyers offer an initial consultation for free, elsewhere you would have to pay a modest fee.

Comment: A withdrawal slip? I suggest you use a different bank that has 21st-century methods. Withdraw all the money from the first present bank right away, before they take the rest of it.

Comment: Did you fie a police report?  In what country did this happen?

Comment: In us in florida

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an in-person withdrawal and not an electronic fund transfer, this is covered by state law and terms of the contract. The contract will not disavow bank liability in case a person forges a signature. The customer has a duty to report the unauthorized signature in a timely fashion, see [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4/4-406). The bank does make a [warranty](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4/4-208#4-208) that they won't knowingly pay an altered or unauthorized instrument, but the onus is on the customer to establish that there is a forgery.

If you wait too long to file a formal complaint, you are out of luck. Of course it depends on what country you are in, whether the banking laws offer any protection.

Comment: Which country does this answer apply to? I can guess, but it would be easier if you edited it in.